# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry with jar command

Tags: java, jar

So I have these classes which im trying to compress into an executable jar file using java's built in javac and jar commands. All the files compile fine without any errors, however; when I try to jar the files using the following command: `jar cfe Project2.jar -cp . SimpleMain.class Connection.class Frame.class Listener.class SimpleNode.class SimpleNode$connectionType.class SimpleNode$Failure.class SimpleNode$nodeName.class Switch.class`, the program throws a ZipException at me and crashes which in turn produces a corrupt jar file which I am unable of extracting any sort of information from using `jar tvf Project2.jar`.

The exception thrown:

```
    java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: SimpleMain.class
            at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.putNextEntry(ZipOutputStream.java:232)
            at java.util.jar.JarOutputStream.putNextEntry(JarOutputStream.java:109)
            at sun.tools.jar.Main.addFile(Main.java:839)
            at sun.tools.jar.Main.create(Main.java:545)
            at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:214)
            at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1288)
```

Comment: `-cp` is not a valid option for the `jar` command.  You are adding both the files in the current directory (`.`) and adding `SimpleMain.class` explicitly, which is the reason for the duplicate entry.  Solution:  remove `-cp .` from the command.

Comment: if I do that, I am presented with ``Error: Could not find or load main class SimpleMain.class``. For other projects I have the ``-cp .`` have fixed that

Comment: The `e` in `cfe` specifies that the argument after the jar file name will be the jar’s main class for execution.  This means that the first argument following the jar file name is treated as a class name and is not added to the .jar file.  Either remove the `e` or change the command to `jar cfe Project2.jar SimpleMain SimpleMain.class …`.

Comment: Even when replacing the ``-cp .`` with ``SimpleMain``, I am faced with the same error of not finding the main class. Any idea why?

Comment: When you run the Java program, you should not specify the `.class` part.  `java -cp Project2.jar SimpleMain` is correct.  There should be no “.class” in the command that runs the program.

Comment: Still getting the same error if I use: ``java -cp Project2.jar SimpleMain``